# css transform: scale3d and translate3d

Tags: css, 3d, transform, styling

why is this not working?

```
transform: scale3d(0.5,0.5,0) translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
```

It only works without the "scale" part, but I thought I was able to pass multiple attributes into the transform.

Comment: Are you really trying to `scale3d(0.5,0.5,0)` or `scale3d(0.5,0.5,1)`? I think the former would make it invisible.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What do you expect to happen? What is actually happening?

Comment: I have the same problem and when I only have scale set scaling actually happens.  When I also set translate no transformation occurs at all. @Marten Zander did you find a solution?